# Draw SVG Path with attribute value grater than 2147483786

Tags: d3.js, svg

I want to draw a svg path where the data is coming from server. Now let suppose one data point is coming as 2147483787. With such big value, my complete path become omit. See the below code snippet for your reference. This will dring nothing on svg. When i give the value <=2147483786, then path is drawn.

```
var simpleLine = d3.svg.line();
d3.select('svg')
.append('path')
.attr({
d: simpleLine([[0,0],[200,200],[2147483787,2147483787]]),
stroke: '#000'
});
```

Comment: an option would be to devide all all values by a constant factor, like 100 if that is OK for you

Comment: That seems to be a browser's bug, works fine on FF but doesn't on Chrome : https://jsfiddle.net/2hoccewv/ **actually it does also happens on FF** but with higher values https://jsfiddle.net/2hoccewv/1/

Comment: You can use D3's scales to transform the coordinates into screen coordinates (I'm assuming that your screen size is less than 2147483786 by 2147483786 pixels).

Comment: I am using the d3 scale only. but my scale is range from 0 to 1000 so the value coming is very high such that d3 scale gives the pixel value equal to the long value i mention. One option is that i will change the scale based upon data received so that scale range from min to max of data. But the problem is what if user change the scale from 0 to 1000 or some small value. Is this a good idea that i make a check in my code that if d3 scale gives the pixel value >2147483786 then simply change that to 2147483786.